# Copy wordpress site from my server

Tags: wordpress

i have an wordpress website on my server but i don't own the domain anymore.
I can access to this site using total commander or filezilla but i can't access that page using google chrome. I want to copy that website. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do few things like:

1. **Files:** From the FileZilla, download all **Files**
2. **Database:** From PhpMyAdmin if you have access download database, if you do not have that, then as you have FTP access, upload a lightweight mysql manager like this ONE file, https://www.adminer.org/ , upload it , and then give login for the database.  You can get database login info from wp-config.php which you can access via FTP. And then EXPORT mysql database dump...
3. **New Domain:** Once you have both files and database, you can load them to any server or WAMP/LAMP on your local pc, and then do search replace for the URL from old domain to new domain like using , this awesome script: https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB

And it will make your site functional on new URL/Domain from existing site files and database.

Comment: I didi copy website to the ftp and i have downloaded database but what to do with them exactly :P

Comment: Great to know! Good luck!